# Is it possible stream files to the client directly from S3 using AWS-SDK?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to stream files to the client side without downloading the file via GetObject method and pipe this response back. Is it possible?

When I do this:

```
s3.getObject(params).on('httpHeaders', function (statusCode, headers) {
           res.set('Accept-Ranges', headers['accept-ranges'])
           res.set('Content-Length', headers['content-length']);
           res.set('Content-Type', headers['content-type']);
         })
         .createReadStream().pipe(res);
```

I'm storing the s3 object in the server memory and piping back to the client.

Is there any way to do this without store the file in the server-side memory?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just send the s3 path(If its a public bucket) to your client and download the file using [File Saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)